# Is 'a' differentiable in f when f is a product of a differentiable and non-differentiable function?

Tags: calculus, functional-analysis, functions, derivatives

Recently, I was studying differentiable and non-differentiable functions and I wondered whether this "conjecture" of mine is true:

1)
"If $f(x)$ is a function that is the product of $g(x)$ and $h(x)$ where $g(x)$ is differentiable at point "a" and $h(x)$ is not, then, by the product rule, $f(x)$ is not differentiable at point $x=a$. "

However, I then endeavoured to apply this theorem to rational functions, sum functions and other functions and quickly I saw that the same "conjecture" holds true for my applied cases. So, I then made a new conjecture:

2) "If $f(x)$ is a function combining the functions $g(x)$ and $h(x)$ by some operation, and $g(x)$ is differentiable at point $x=a$ and $h(x)$ is not, then $f(x)$ is not differentiable at point $x=a$".

My first endeavour to prove this "new conjecture" was to simply check the validity of it in all the different possible operations, that is, addition, subtraction Et Cetera, where, to speed the process, I could prove that if the conjecture holds for one operation then it must also hold for the inverse of that operation. But, I simply do not have the time to devote myself to such things, though it may be not at all time-consuming a task, and so I tried to find a contradiction of this conjecture but I was unable to. So, my question is, can anyone hint me at a contradiction or at a method of proof as time-consuming as a proof by contradiction, but before all that tell me whether this conjecture is even valid, been spoken of, or simply downright idiotic.

(Note: it would appreciated if my lack of mathematical terminology could be fixed by editing when necessary)

(Note: It would be helpful to avoid the trivial case where $x=0$)

Comment: If $g$ is differentiable at $a$, and $g(a) = 0$, and $h$ is continuous at $a$, then $f = g\cdot h$ is differentiable at $a$, whether $h$ is differentiable there or not.

Comment: If $g$ is the zero function $g(x)=0$ then it is differentiable and any product with another function is the zero function too.

Comment: @Daniel Fischer I know this was not part of the question, and perhaps I will edit my question to add this, but cigs there a case where $x$ is a non-zero integer or real number?

Comment: $F(x)=x|x|$ is a good example in this context.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You consider $f(x)=F(g(x),h(x))$ where $F$ may be one of several "standard operations" and wonder if it is possible to have $f,g$ differentiable at $a$ and $h$ not.

For $F(u,v)=u+v$ your conjecture is ture because we obtain that $h(x)=f(x)-g(x)$ is the difference of differentiable functions. Similarly for $F(u,v)=u-v$.

For $F(u,v)=uv$ we have the trivial counterexample $g(x)=0$ for all $x$. But also $g(a)=0$ with $h$ continuous (except perhaps at $a$) is a counterexample.
However, if *additionally* we have $g(a)\ne 0$, then $h(x)=\frac{f(x)}{g(x)}$ is differentiable by the quotient rule.

The argument for $F(u,v)=\frac uv$ (with $h(a)\ne0$) is similar.

For $F(u,v)=\frac vu$ we find immediately that $h(x)=f(x)g(x)$ is differentiable.

Another interstting question would be about $f(x)=g(h(x))$ or $f(x)=h(g(x))$. For these $h$ can be quite wild unless $g$ is injective near $a$.

Comment: What about power functions or root functions?

Answer (score 2):

What you can say is that $f$ *may not be* differentiable. For example, take $g(x)=0$, and $h(x)=|x|$. Then clearly $f(x)=g(x)h(x)=0$ is differentiable.

What you *can* say, though, is the following:

> If $g$ is differentiable in $x$ *and* $g'(x)\ne 0$, then $g(x)h(x)$ is differentiable if and only if $h(x)$ is.

If you want something more general than the product, suppose that:
$$
f(x) = F(g(x),h(x))
$$

for a differentiable (2-variable) function $F$. Then if $g,h$ are differentiable, $f$ is differentiable, and:
$$
f'(x) = \frac{\partial F}{\partial g}\frac{dg}{dx} + \frac{\partial F}{\partial h}\frac{dh}{dx},
$$

which implies that:

> if $F$ above is differentiable, and $h$ is *not* (at a point x), then $f'$ is differentiable if and only if:
>   $$
> \frac{\partial F}{\partial h} = 0.
> $$

Comment: Sorry, but I thought that since the modulus functions is non-differentiable at $0$ then this means that it's derivative is undefined at $0$ and can thus not be assigned a value. However, in the product rule, the function $g(x)$ at 0 (0) is multiplied by the derivative of the modulus function at 0 which is undefined, and I'm not certain whether one can multiply an undefined value by 0 and obtain zero.

Comment: How does $F(x)=x|x|$ fit into your first framework??

Comment: @JpMcCarthy Is that directed at me or at geodude? For, if it is for me, I edited the question to ask for trivial examples when $x=0$.

Comment: I meant non-trivial cases when $x$ does not equal $0$.